# Excluding Columns From SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

Hello I'm trying to know how to exclude columns from SELECT statement , 
I have 2 tables joined.

First Table:

```
 |--ID--|--Name--|--Date 1--|--Date 2--|
```

Second Table:

```
|--ID--|--Tax--|--Total--|
```

Output:

```
  |--ID--|--Name--|--Date 1--|--Date 2--|--ID--|--Tax--|--Total--|
```

This is the output what i want:

```
   |--Name--|--Tax--|--Total|
```

Here's my Code:

```
Dim loadq As String =
            "SELECT HelperEmpEarns.*, HelperEmpDed.*" & _
            "FROM (HelperEmpEarns RIGHT JOIN HelperEmpDed ON HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID) " & _
            "WHERE [Position] LIKE '%Helper%' AND [Pday1] >= # " & MetroDateTime1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND [Pday2] <= # " & MetroDateTime2.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID"
```

Comment: instead of including all column using * , just use the table name with column to get specific columns from tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your select statement more specific and get rid of the wildcard(s) *

```
SELECT firstTable.Name, SecondTable.Tax, SecondTable.Total
    ...
```

Take a look at [w3schools SQL SELECT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) for more information about the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just enumerate the fields you want to show, instead of putting *, which means "all fields":

```
Dim loadq As String =
                "SELECT HelperEmpEarns.[Name], HelperEmpDed.Tax, HelperEmpDed.Total" & _
                "FROM (HelperEmpEarns RIGHT JOIN HelperEmpDed ON HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID) " & _
                "WHERE [Position] LIKE '%Helper%' AND [Pday1] >= # " & MetroDateTime1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND [Pday2] <= # " & MetroDateTime2.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID"
```

I put [Name] in square brackets to help identify it as a field name rather than a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Select HelperEmpEarns.*` will return all column names from the table.  This is generally not considered a good development practice.

A much preferred method is to get back only the columns that you need `Select HelperEmpEarns.Col1Name, HelperEmpEarns.Col2Name...`

This has several advantages:

1. If someone changes the database design and adds or removes columns, it will not affect your query unless they're removing one of the columns you need.
2. You possibly have a much smaller return dataset than if you return all columns.

So, change it like this:

```
Dim loadq As String =
            "SELECT HelperEmpEarns.Col1Name, HelperEmpEarns.Col2Name, HelperEmpEarns.Col3Name, " & _
            "HelperEmpDed.Col1Name, HelperEmpDed.Col2Name" & _
            "FROM (HelperEmpEarns RIGHT JOIN HelperEmpDed ON HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID) " & _
            "WHERE [Position] LIKE '%Helper%' AND [Pday1] >= # " & MetroDateTime1.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND [Pday2] <= # " & MetroDateTime2.Value.ToShortDateString & "# AND HelperEmpEarns.EmpPID = HelperEmpDed.EmpPID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `select` only the required columns instead of everything`(*)`

```
SELECT HelperEmpEarns.Name, HelperEmpDed.Tax,HelperEmpDed.Total 
from..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firsttable.name,secondtable.tax,secondtable.total 
FROM firsttable 
JOIN secondtable using(ID);
```